# Best way to log users programmatically into a 3rd party website (when OAuth is unavailable)?

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I'm working on an asp.net website that needs to store user passwords for another website so that I can retrieve data periodically without requiring the user to keep logging in.  I can't imagine how one-way hashes would work in this case since the user isn't going to be re-keying the password every time.  I'm assuming I need to encrypt the passwords to store in a SQL Server database and decrypt them when needed. But that's where things get tough for me.  The basic infrastructure is a C#/Asp.Net MVC3 website running on load-balanced Azure compute instances and storing data in SQL Azure.  I'm not a crypto guy, and I don't want to make a rookie mistake.  There seems to be a lot of information out there, but nothing seems clear to me.  Even though the data I'm connecting to isn't sensitive, I want to treat my users' information with the same care I want my personal data treated. Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I certainly understand that storing passwords is not a best practice, but in some cases it is simply unavoidable.  I have come across this project, but have not tried it yet: http://securentity.codeplex.com/.  It uses a digital certificate on the web server.

Users of the 3rd party site are able to set their data as "public", in which case I wouldn't need to store their password.  So I may give users the option of doing that instead.

Comment: I didn't get past the first line. If you're storing passwords, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm not actually doing anything yet, which is why I'm asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) and [Single Sign-On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on).
In simple terms: Only an authentication token is sent between the different systems.

You (the site) should **never** have knowledge about the users passwords. At most you should know the **hash** of the passwords to **your** site.

Read the two topics above and you will know how to properly secure your and the "neighbour" site.

**Edit**

In Short:
The *other* site (site B) implements OAuth server processes. Your site (site A) implements OAuth client authentication. When requesting user information from site B you redirect the user to site B authentication to allow site A to read information from site B regarding the user. Site B creates a token that site A can use to access the information. This token can be time limited (or not).

Comment: But wouldn't the 3rd party site, over which I have no control, have to be providing an OAuth implementation?

Comment: Sure it does... If the third party does NOT implement OAuth or some kind of Single Sign-On then I'd strongly advise not to do it since it is not secure for ANY part. The information cannot be trusted.

Comment: The only way to access the third party site (which you have no control over) without OAuth or Single Sign-On is to store the passwords. And that is, to me, not an acceptable solution. You need to convince the third party site to implement a better security scheme IF they want to share information.